# UI when having many-to-one table relations

Tags: forms, gui-design

Let's say I have a database `employees-manager` and that I have two tables: `employees` and `salaries`. Also, let's say that `employees` table have only 2 columns (emp_id and name_of_employee) and `salaries` table have 3 columns (salaries_id, emp_id (foreign key) and amount). Now, the problem is that I'm not sure how to create my form for enterence of salaries since I have to choose employee from some component and selected value must contain id of employee (of course, chosing only name would make relation between tables meaningless). One of potential approaches:

[image]
[image]

Problem with this approach is if you have many employees. First, it will be painful for user to find desired employee. Second, employees are loaded "eagerly". Can someone tell me how to deal with situation like this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming that all your employees get paid, sounds to me like in terms of UI it's just one simple table where the Salary field is editable.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwpsA0.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: So, to make table with those columns, to load all employees in it and then to edit their salaries? *EDIT* Actually, by that logic, I won't even need `Salaries` form, I could all do in `Employees` form?

Comment: Yes. You do need to make it very clear which employee is marked, so people don't make mistakes here. So I'd make the Name column adjacent to the Salary column, and make sure to highlight the selected row very clearly.